# Privilieges escalation with ansible using bastion/jump server

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Is using:

```
become: true
become_user: root
```

Something that is ignored when using jump host ? I'm connecting to my destination server using:

```
"ANSIBLE_SSH_COMMON_ARGS": "-o ProxyCommand='ssh -p 22 -W %h:%p -q user@ip_obfuscated -i /home/semaphore/.ssh/jump.priv'"
```

The whole connection when i run debug looks like:

```
<ip_obfuscated> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/tmp/semaphore/access_key_136706914"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="terraform"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ProxyCommand=ssh -p 22 -W %h:%p -q user@ip_obfuscated -i /home/semaphore/.ssh/jump.priv' -o 'ControlPath="/tmp/semaphore/.ansible/cp/1713c02767"' ip_obfuscated '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/terraform/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo /home/terraform/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1668542130.3374832-2167-135826106011908 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1668542130.3374832-2167-135826106011908="` echo /home/terraform/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1668542130.3374832-2167-135826106011908 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
```

Which works just fine, but I'm always connected only as an simple user... I can't escalate the privileges... look at this result:

```
---
- name: Remove user from Linux server
  hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:

    # Use whoami to determine the current user
    - name: Determine current user
      shell: whoami
      register: current_user
    # print the current user
    - name: Print current user
      debug:
        msg: "Current user is {{ current_user.stdout }}"

    - name: Determine current user
      shell: sudo whoami
      register: current_user2
    # print the current user
    - name: Print current user
      debug:
        msg: "Current user is {{ current_user2.stdout }}"
```

Result:

```
 9:12:34 PM
9:12:34 PM
TASK [Print current user] ******************************************************
9:12:34 PM
ok: [ip_obfuscated] => {
9:12:34 PM
"msg": "Current user is terraform"
9:12:34 PM
}
9:12:38 PM
9:12:38 PM
TASK [Determine current user] **************************************************
9:12:38 PM
changed: [ip_obfuscated]
9:12:38 PM
9:12:38 PM
TASK [Print current user] ******************************************************
9:12:38 PM
ok: [ip_obfuscated] => {
9:12:38 PM
"msg": "Current user is root"
9:12:38 PM
}
9:12:38 PM
```

I'm using up to date ansible.

I tried so many combinations of become, become_user, become_method... set it globally, set it on task it self, even in inventory... no idea why it wont become root on its own...